# Is there a way to get the value of `100%` when used for the `height` or `weight` props in React Native StyleSheet?

Tags: react-native

Let say that I have the following:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  outerContainer: {
    height: dynamicHeight,
    width: dynamicWidth,
  },
  innerContainer: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%,
  },
});
```

**Question**

Is there a way to get the value of what `100%` will be for the `height` and `width` props in `styles.innerContainer`?

**Deeper Dive into Problem**

I have a React Native iPad app.

- It allows you to read pages in both Portrait and Landscape orientations.
- Sometimes, `outerContainer.height` will be less than the height of the iPad. In those scenarios, we want `dynamicValue` to default to the height of the iPad.

Maybe there is another approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

With [Dimension](https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions), you can get your device size.

```
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

In your stylesheet you can then do something like that:

```
StyleSheet.create({
      outerContainer: {
        height: windowHeight,
        width: windowWidth,
      },
      innerContainer: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%,
      },
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment Dallas, but that's not quite what I was asking for. `outerContainer` is not the size of the device so therefore I cannot use those values.